Person sells chometz at home and travels west for Pesach. When does he get his chometz back?
Someone is going away from home for Pesach in a westerly direction. He sells his chometz in his home town through his Rav in his home town. Normally the chometz reverts back to the owner immediately after Pesach in the home town. At that time it will still be Yom Tov for the person away from home in the West. Does the traveller have a problem of then owning this sold chometz or does it only become his after he wishes to acquire it which will be after Yom Tov in his holiday location?

There's also the issue of eating chometz that doesn't belong to you on Erev Pesach after the sale. Usually there will be a separate sale arrangement for people leaving town.

does it only become his after he wishes to acquire it - I was just told by a rov that this is the case. It was regarding chametz located on the West Coast but sold on the East Coast (according to the view that the location of the chametz matters), but I assume the same principle applies.

Minchat Yitzchak 6:45- The issue of repurchasing chametz is addressed by arguing that according to halacha it isn't necessary for the rabbi to conduct a formal act (a kinyan) to buy back the chametz from the non-Jew. The rationale behind this argument lies in the absence of a requirement for the rabbi to possess a document authorizing him to act as an agent for all those whose chametz he sold to the non-Jew. The absence of such a document indicates that a formal act of kinyan isn't truly necessary for the repurchase of the chametz. This is because, since the non-Jew is obligated to pay for any chametz that they choose to keep, their failure to remove the chametz from the Jewish seller's property and pay for it demonstrates their intention to undo the original sale. The suggestion by certain halachic authorities, such as the Bigdei Yesha and Biur Halacha, that the rabbi should perform a kinyan is primarily to avoid the misconception that selling chametz is not a genuine transaction. However, despite its authenticity, a formal act of kinyan is not fundamentally required for the repurchase of the chametz. Therefore, he argues that when the rabbi repurchases the chametz, he does so on his own behalf. Similar to the non-Jew who must pay for the chametz to keep possession, the rabbi must also pay the full value if he wishes to keep possession of the seller's chametz. Consequently, the same reasoning as before applies to the rabbi; namely, if he fails to remove the chametz from the seller's property and pay for it, it indicates his lack of desire to retain ownership. Thus, when the seller takes back the chametz, he acquires it, even without expressing anything to the rabbi.
Shulchan Aruch Harav OC 448:3; 450:21 in parentheses- there is no Halachic issue involved with being located in a later time zone and having the Chametz bought back after Pesach in the earlier time zone, as one has no intention to buy back the Chametz until after Pesach ends for him.
Igrot Moshe 4:94-- one should sell the Chametz in the earlier time zone and tell the Rav to not buy it back from the gentile on his behalf, until Pesach ends in his later time zone.
Hope this helps!
Links used:

https://dinonline.org/2023/04/14/shemini-pitfalls-of-people-who-travel-for-pesach-to-a-different-time-zone/
https://shulchanaruchharav.com/mechiras-chometz-when-traveling-to-different-time-zones/#_ftnref8

